# How to disable android mediaplayer FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, android, exception, android-mediaplayer

I have `VideoView` which gets its URI from http protocol, this URI is very private to me, however in `setVideoURI` the system throws a `debugging exception` like this:

`07-06 10:35:10.920: D/MediaPlayer(7799): java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider:` ...and my private url appear here

I traced the problem to android `MediaPlayer` (which is used in `VideoView`) [setDataSource](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.1_r2/android/media/MediaPlayer.java#MediaPlayer.setDataSource%28android.content.Context%2Candroid.net.Uri%29)

This is what happens in setDataSource:

```
public void setDataSource(Context context, Uri uri)
        throws IOException, IllegalArgumentException, SecurityException, IllegalStateException {

        /****
            Test if URI is in assets, and of course HTTP (in my case) will not!
        ****/
        AssetFileDescriptor fd = null;
        try {
            ContentResolver resolver = context.getContentResolver();
            fd = resolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(uri, "r");
            if (fd == null) {
                return;

        } catch (SecurityException ex) {
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            /****
                Here is the exception which let me crazy :(
            ****/
        } finally {
            if (fd != null) {
                fd.close();
            }
        }

        /****
            So set HTTP here!
        ****/

        setDataSource(uri.toString());
        return;
 }
```

Actually the exception thrown in [openAssetFileDescriptor](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.1_r2/android/content/ContentResolver.java#ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor%28android.net.Uri%2Cjava.lang.String%29) method

So, what's the recommended way to prevent this exception in LogCat?

This is what I have tried:

1- Catch `setVideoURI` Exceptions.

2- `Use ProGaurd assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log`, but this works on application context only (and MediaPlayer is the system context).

I don't recommend an override system class for compatibility reasons.

Comment: Resolve the problem by getting files from DCIM folder on the device, but not using getContentResolver to get the path.

Comment: Content providers don't support remote exceptions yet. I suspect the media provider will be throwing some sort of exception